# How to add custom fields to GitHub issue template?

Tags: github, github-api

Based on GitHub documentation I can create a custom Bug Report template, and in that i can customize the Markup that fits the business need.

OOTB bug and custom templates have same fields (Assignees, Projects, Labels, Milestones... etc)
But how can I add custom fields to it (For e.g. Priority, Severity, Planning Status etc...)

Another example is AzureDevOps allows definition of custom templates and custom fields for bugs or feature enhancements.

Can I achieve similar in GitHub templates ?

Comment: Custom fields are coming. See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61473541/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apr. 2020: From [the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository), there do not seem to be any option to add custom fields.

That maybe because of the management involved with any new field: for instance, limiting the values of "Priority" to only a fixed set (like "low", "medium"  and "high")
Since each custom field would require its own set of rules and validation, this is not currently available for GitHub issue template.

---

Update June 2021:

> ### [New beta features within GitHub Issues, with better ways to plan, track, and manage projects](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-23-whats-new-with-github-issues/).

> Read more on the [GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/features/issues) or in the [FAQ](http://github.com/features/issues#faq).
> ✨ NEW – Project planning for developers
>
> Available in limited public beta
>
> Built like a spreadsheet, [project tables](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience/about-projects) give you a live canvas to filter, sort, and group issues and pull requests.
>
> **Tailor them to your needs with custom fields and saved views.**
>
> [Sign up for the beta now](https://github.com/features/issues).

Comment: thanks @VonC i raised an enhancement request with GitHub support...

Comment: @ameya Great. Let me know (and others reading this question) what it comes of that enhancement request.